# How do I extract variable data from a line of string with tags?

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm trying to write Java code to go to a website, read the HTML code line-by-line, extract certain pieces of data, including an embedded URL to go to another website, and repeat the process 100 times. 
I've been able to isolate most of the pieces of data I need using expressions like:

```
s.ranking = line.substring(line.indexOf(">")+1, line.length() -7);
```

But I'm having problems with the following line:

```
<strong>Writer:</strong> Dylan <br/><strong>Producer:</strong> Tom Wilson&nbsp <br/><strong>Released:</strong> July &#039;65, Columbia<br/>12 weeks; No. 2</p>
```

I need to extract and save the Writer data (Dylan). The producer data (Tom Wilson) and the Release date data (July '65). Some of the pages will have multiple writers and will be labeled "Writers:", and some will have multiple producers, labeled "Producers:"

How do I capture "Dylan" ,"Tom Wilson" and "July '65" from the above line in Java?

Thank you very much!
DM

Comment: Have you tried an HTML parser such as jsoup?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm not familiar with HTML parsers. I'm doing this for a class and am learning about finding, isolating and extracting data.

Comment: tldr; Do *not* use a regular expression for this. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use HTML parser. But as i read your comment " I'm doing this for a class and am learning about finding, isolating and extracting data."

What you can do something like :

```
String producer = "Producer:";
String writer = "Writer:";
String released = "Released:";

String s = "<strong>Writer:</strong> Dylan <br/><strong>Producer:</strong> Tom Wilson&nbsp <br/><strong>Released:</strong> July &#039;65, Columbia<br/>12 weeks; No. 2</p>  ";
int writerIndex = s.lastIndexOf(writer);
int producerIndex = s.lastIndexOf(producer);
int realesedIndex = s.lastIndexOf(released);

String writerExtracted = s.substring(writerIndex + writer.length(),
        producerIndex).replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
System.out.println(writerExtracted);

String producerExtracted = s.substring(
        producerIndex + producer.length(), realesedIndex).replaceAll(
        "\\<.*?>", "");
System.out.println(producerExtracted);

String releasedExtracted = s.substring(
        realesedIndex + released.length(), s.length()).replaceAll(
        "\\<.*?>", "");
System.out.println(releasedExtracted);
```

**Output:**

```
 Dylan 
 Tom Wilson&nbsp 
 July &#039;65, Columbia12 weeks; No. 2
```

**NOTE:** you can get rid of signs such as &#039 or &nbsp  using another regex ...

Comment: Based on above comments, I'd rather use an HTML parser, I just don't know how. In this example, how would I account for the fact that "Producer:" and "Writer:" are sometimes plural?

Comment: easy , is there separator between words like "," ? or just a whitespace?